# Lost GridView SelectIndexChanged at UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, webusercontrol, web-user-controls

I have a UserControl which contain GridView.I set AutoGenerateSelectButton is true for this GridView.
But it didn't work when I press Select inside UserControl.
Do you have anyidea?

Answer (score 0):

You should move your event handling to the page that owns the UserControl and not in the UserControl

Inside the Page_Load of your page, add this

```
myUserControl.FindControl("GridView1"));
dvGrid.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Add the handler to the page

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //access the GridView
     GridView grid = (GridView) sender;

     //access the selected row
     GridViewRow selectedRow = grid.SelectedRow;

     //access the selected Primary key - make sure you set the DataKeyNames property of the GridView to the Record Id - in your Markup
     string currentRowPrimaryKey = grid.SelectedValue;
     //OR
     string currentRowPrimaryKey = grid.SelectedDataKey.Value;

}
```

Now you have several values to play with. You can put a break point and examine the properties of the sender to have more options. Good Luck

Comment: Hi bro,I tried with your suggestion.But it didn't work.May you disscuss with me on chat

Comment: It didn't show debug at main page.Also didn't show event at UserControl too.